# Laravel attach manytomany with extra field

Tags: php, laravel

There are 3 tables. Products, Users and product_user. There are 3 fields in product_user table. product_id, user_id and price.

product_id and user_id will be attached and filled automatically. But I want a textfield named price which user fill it to be inserted in price field in database.

I mean I want to insert a textfield when attaching.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried ? How you are doing this ?

Comment: Thank you it's done by Nikolas Diakosavvas answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To insert an extra field in your pivot table first of all, you need to specify this extra field in your models.

**For Example this:**

In Product model

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'product_user')
                    ->withPivot('price');
}
```

In User model

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_user')
                    ->withPivot('price');
}
```

Furthermore, in you Controller you can attach this extra field like this:

```
$product->users()->attach($user_id, ['price'=> $price ]);
```

I hope this will help you !!!

Comment: thank you so much, It worked perfectly as I desired.

Comment: if you want to add multiple columns you can all write as follows 
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_user')
                    ->withPivot(['price','another_column']);

Comment: @dvijparekh Yes !! brackets ("[]") are not necessary, you can write
 `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_user') ->withPivot('price','another_column');`

Answer (score 1):

A best practice example to pass one array to `attach` is this example:

```
   $extra = array(
               
                'expense_type_id' => $request->expenseType,
                'quantity' => $request->quantity,
                'price' => $request->price
            );  
            //dd($extra);   
            
            $logisticCost->expenses()->attach($logisticCost->id,$extra);
```

Cheers!